# Error 404 when reload on Render and Vercel

Tags: reactjs, react-router, render, vite, vercel

I've created a React app using Vite and I'm using react-router, and deployed it successfully both to Render and Vercel.

The app works perfectly well **except** for when trying to reload a page that is not the home page. for example:

trying to reload *'www.myapp.com/about'* will result in an *'error 404'*, while reloading *'www.myapp.com'* will work properly.

This led to the conclusion that the problem probably lies in my app settings but I'm really not sure on how to solve it. When searching online I came across other people in the exact / similar situation but with no solid solution.

If anybody has an idea on what I'm talking about - I would love to share the relevant pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

Solution Source : https://medium.com/today-i-solved/deploy-spa-with-react-router-to-vercel-d10a6b2bfde8

Quick Solution --
Make vercel.json file in your root directory, then add redirect rules like below.

```
{
  "routes": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).